# I'm trying to connect to mySql db in my server but whenever i try to do that the application shut down on its own

Tags: java, mysql

Hello i have a problem connecting to mySql Db on my server whenever i try to do so it shut down on its own i have imorted the jdbc lib into my project this version of it(mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar)

here is my connection class

```
Connection connection;
Statement statement;
public Database() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://ip:3306/test", "root", "pass");
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        //test = "Connected succefully";
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        //  e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        //test = e.getMessage();
        System.err.println(e);
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and here is my error in the logcat error

```
2019-03-04 14:11:36.701 16708-16708/com.example.sony.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sony.test, PID: 16708 <br />
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sony.test/com.example.sony.test.settings}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:383)
        at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrlParser.isConnectionStringSupported(ConnectionUrlParser.java:152)
        at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrl.acceptsUrl(ConnectionUrl.java:258)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:187)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:569)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:219)
        at com.example.sony.test.Database.<init>(Database.java:25)
        at com.example.sony.test.settings.onCreate(settings.java:61)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
```

Answer (score 0):

i have been able to fix that problem, i just tried an older version of mysql-connector-java but now it throw an exception : could not create connection to database server.

Comment: well if there is anyone looking for solution to the same problem i have found one just add this to your database class or your activity 
=====>StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);